# Write text and dynamics vertically centered

Tags: lilypond, dynamics

I've been rewriting this piece using a `PianoStaff` with `Staff`, `Dynamics`, `Staff` scores as others have suggested and haven't found an easy way to represent the "rit. descresc" dynamics below

[image: rit. descres]

Neither on the G not F staff I have been able to write this as the text markup moves above/below center. ie:

[image: example]

**Working example**

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "espanol"

derecha = \relative do'' {
  \clef treble
  \key re \major
  
  <sol si>8 (la si re)  <re mi,>4 <dos mi,>
}

izquierda = \relative do {
  \clef bass
  \key re \major
  
  sol8 (re' sol si)  la, (mi' la mi)
}

dynamics = {
  s4s4 { s8 -\markup \italic "rit." s4\> s4\! }
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "one" \derecha
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \dynamics
    \new Staff = "two" \izquierda
  >>
}
```

Comment: Doesn't *rit.* and other tempo markings usually go above the upper staff?

Comment: Not sure about that. I've a few scores I'm transcribing and all of them have dynamics centered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that markup text is aligned differently than dynamics. Dynamics are centered by default, so **the solution is to make LilyPond think that "rit." is a dynamic marking**.

This is accomplished with the `make-dynamic-script` function (see [New Dynamic Marks](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/new-dynamic-marks) in the LilyPond manual). The below code is based off the example given in the linked manual page.

There are two new lines added to the OP code

```
ritMarkup = \markup { \normal-text \italic rit. }

ritDynamic = #(make-dynamic-script ritMarkup)
```

and an alteration to the definition of the `dynamics` variable, to incorporate the newly created dynamic mark.

```
dynamics = {
  s4s4 { s8 -\ritDynamic s4\> s4\! }
}
```

Here is the complete code.

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "espanol"

ritMarkup = \markup { \normal-text \italic rit. }

ritDynamic = #(make-dynamic-script ritMarkup)

derecha = \relative do'' {
  \clef treble
  \key re \major
  
  <sol si>8 (la si re)  <re mi,>4 <dos mi,>
}

izquierda = \relative do {
  \clef bass
  \key re \major
  
  sol8 (re' sol si)  la, (mi' la mi)
}

dynamics = {
  s4s4 { s8 -\ritDynamic s4\> s4\! }
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "one" \derecha
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \dynamics
    \new Staff = "two" \izquierda
  >>
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the dynamics block is written like that, `dynamics = { s2 s2-\ritDynamic\> | s1\! | }` is much cleaner.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I wanted to make the fewest possible changes to the OP's code in order to stay focused on the core of the answer. But you could pose the question to the OP. Perhaps they had a specific reason, or maybe just didn't realize they could.

Comment: I think OP was only trying to prevent the the hairpin from stacking on top of the "rit." marking.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Possibly. But again, you're probably better off asking the OP.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola Alwin!

Adding to Aaron’s great response:
Yes, the way to go would be to simply add the text as a dynamic marking. If you need this with more control rather than defining a variable `...Dynamic` for each marking you can outsource this into an utility function:

```
"d" =
#(define-scheme-function (m) (markup?)
   (make-dynamic-script (markup #:normal-text m)))
```

Now we can simply do `{ c'\d"rit."\< d' e'\! }`. But since we might often want to have italic text we might not want to add `\markup\italic` just for that, so let’s do

```
di = #(define-scheme-function (m) (markup?) (d (markup #:italic m)))
```

Now we can simply do `{ c'\di"rit."\< d' e'\! }`. Now, we do see a difference in alignment with this dynamic markup and a normal markup:

```
{ c'\di\markup\circle"rit."\< d' e'\! }
{ c'_\markup\italic\circle"rit." d' e' }
```

This is because the `DynamicText` grob has `parent-alignment-X` and `self-alignment-X` as `#CENTER` by default, so it will be centered upon itself and it will be placed relative to the center of it’s X-parent. `TextScript` grobs on the otherhand have this property unset by default, which defaults to left-alignment. So to get consistency we may do

```
md = \tweak self-alignment-X ##f \tweak parent-alignment-X ##f \d\etc
mdi = \tweak self-alignment-X ##f \tweak parent-alignment-X ##f \di\etc
```

which then allows us to do:

```
{ c'\mdi\markup\circle"rit."\< d' e'\! }
```

So then we get this:

[image]

Applying this to your code we get:

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "espanol"

"d" =
#(define-scheme-function (m) (markup?)
   (make-dynamic-script (markup #:normal-text m)))

di = #(define-scheme-function (m) (markup?) (d (markup #:italic m)))

md = \tweak self-alignment-X ##f \tweak parent-alignment-X ##f \d\etc
mdi = \tweak self-alignment-X ##f \tweak parent-alignment-X ##f \di\etc

derecha = \relative do'' {
  \clef treble
  \key re \major
  
  <sol si>8 (la si re)  <re mi,>4 <dos mi,>
}

izquierda = \relative do {
  \clef bass
  \key re \major
  
  sol8 (re' sol si)  la, (mi' la mi)
}

dynamics = {
  s4s4 s4.\mdi"rit."\> s8\!
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "one" \derecha
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \dynamics
    \new Staff = "two" \izquierda
  >>
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm getting lost at all the function definition examples around but you managed to nail it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @AlwinKesler I know that feeling. The concept of music functions can be a bit confusing at the start. If you feel confused about something, always feel free to drop a message on the lilypond-user mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user This is generally where we Ponders hang out, and there is a lot of helpfulness and willingness to explain things on the list.